# How do I find the image with the greatest width in a group of images?

Tags: command-line

Let's say there are 50 images, and I want to know which one has the biggest width. Which commands should I use?

Comment: What type of images? What file format?

Answer (score 1):

This command (identify from ImageMagick) output the image with the biggest width :

```
identify -format "%w %h %f\n" *.png | sort -n -r -k 1  | head -n 1
```

-format "%w %h %f = width, height, filename

Result : w h image.png

Source : Find Largest Image Dimensions in Folder :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155544/find-largest-image-dimensions-in-folder

If your images aren’t in the same folder, open a terminal and run this script from a folder contening subdirectories.

```
find . -iname "*.png" -type f -exec identify -format "%w %h %f\n" '{}' \;      | sort -n -r -k 1 | head -n 1
```

Note : If you have more than one image with the same width it will only show one result. To have a list of all images sort by width remove head -n 1 from the precedent command.

Comment: what does he mean by *.png

Comment: The image format. You can replace by *.jpg, *,jpeg or only * for all image  format.

Comment: * for all image format doesn't work.

Comment: Wildcards: http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm But since that is a very basic question, I might venture to recommend a tutorial on the basics to get past some expected difficulties sure to be encountered, eg https://www.learnshell.org

Answer (score 1):

This command will search for image widths in the current directory.

Before you have to install imageinfo with:

```
sudo apt install imageinfo
```

Then type this command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iregex ".*/.*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\|png\|tiff\|bmp\svg\)" \
    -exec bash -c "echo -ne {}'  '; imageinfo --width {}; echo " \;\
    | sort -k2 -n
```

If you only want the largest one   add a pipe to the command above

```
... | tail -n 1
```

Comment: I oppose putting this in bashrc. If doing it more than once, put it in a script file. I typically keep these in ~/bin, which is usually in the path.